# UISplitViewController: Programmatically Making Popover Controller Access Button Appear on Detail View

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I don't know how to ask this more precisely. I have a master/detail and am creating the whole thing programmatically. I subclasses UISplitViewController and populated it with the two controllers, and everything looks as it should until I set `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation` such that it returns YES in portrait modes.

When I have the master hiding in portrait and portrait upside-down, as expected, it hides. However, I can't add a "Master" button to the nav bar at the top of the detail view in `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController`. This is probably because I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how I'm supposed to accomplish that task.

I followed the Apple examples and did:

```
barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
[detailController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
```

I'm not getting any errors, but no button either. I speculate that perhaps it's because what I'm saving as `detailController` in my subclass is a `UINavigationController` and not a `UIViewController`.

Any guidance on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Having written this, I realized that there were several errors in wiring this whole thing up:

1. `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController` really wants you to not only to set the `barButtonItem` title, but also to add it to the nav bar of the detail controller.
2. If you ever want to programmatically dismiss the popover, you have to store the popover supplied in `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController` someplace in the master view.

So, the answer to the first part of the question was:

```
barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
[[detailController.topViewController navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
```

That got me to the UIViewController that can set a `UIBarButtonItem` on the navigation bar. I'm sure I could have done this directly on the `UINavigationController` but didn't immediately see how.

The second, unasked part of this question, deals with what to do with the popover once it's visible. Again, I needed the detail controller to know what the actual popover was so it can be dismissed, so in `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController`, I added code like:

```
[masterController.navigationItem topViewController].popoverController = pc;
```

where `pc` is the value of the argument passed into the delegate method. Then, in my master controller, I have a `UITableView` and on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I simply did this:

```
if(popoverController)
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

And that's what I learned in iOS school today :)